# Xamarin iOS display detail from UITableview

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I m doing a Xamarin iOS project. I have a UITableView I wan't to select a row when I click in a button and display the information linked to the cell selected.
Like this :

[image: Exemple]

I don't know how to pass data from the first controller to the second when I clicked on the button. How can I do that ?

Here is my TableDataSource :

```
private const string cellIdentifier = "ProductCell";

private ProductListViewController _controller;
private List<Product> _products;

public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            ProductCell cell = (ProductCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);

            if (cell == null)
                cell = new ProductCell(new NSString(cellIdentifier));

            var record = _products[(int)indexPath.Row];
            cell.UpdateCell(record.Image, indexPath.Row);
            cell.Tag = indexPath.Row;

            return cell;
        }
```

Here is my product custom cell :

```
public partial class ProductCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("ProductCell");

        public ProductCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public ProductCell(NSString cellId)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateCell(string imageName, nint tag)
        {
            this.ProductImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(imageName);
            this.MoreBtn.Tag = tag;
        }
}
```

Edit :
Here is my code for the navigation, I will place it in the action button method. But for now I don't know where to create this method :

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

            var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ProductDetailViewController") as ProductDetailViewController;
// Here I Will pass the data to the controller
            _controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
```

Comment: How are you currently doing the navigation from ViewController1 (Products) to ViewController2 (Product Details) ?

Comment: @apineda I added the code if you want to see it. Tell me what do you think about it please

Comment: you already have an instance of the viewcontroller  here 

`var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ProductDetailViewController") as ProductDetailViewController;` 

so you can assign any value to public properties or create a public method where you can pass in your values and make the assignment inside the ViewController.

Comment: @apineda Yes but my problem is that I don't know where to fire the button event to launch this action, because the button is in the ProductCell class and I don't have access to it in my table viewdatasource. How can I do that ? thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GetCell--

```
cell.yourbtn.Tag = indexPath.Row;
cell.getDetailButton.TouchUpInside -= handler;
cell.getDetailButton.TouchUpInside += handler;
```

Here is code for button event handler

```
void handler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            nint tag = btn.Tag;
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

            var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ProductDetailViewController") as ProductDetailViewController;
//  datatopass = yourlistofdata[tag]; Here I Will pass the data to the controller  -
            _controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);


        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's like what I did, just one question why you unsubscribe and subscribe directly in the GetCell Method ?

Comment: GetCell method called multiple time. and it reuse previously created objects. so if you have cell 1 on top, cell 6 not visible at bottom, you scroll up, cell1 is used when you  use "tableView.DequeueReusableCell"  because cell1 is not visible anymore. and on cell1 button, you already have event handler.   so that need to be removed otherwise event called multiple time. Want to confirm that? comment out line which is for removing handler, then scroll down on tableview and click on button, debug  to see that handler is calling multiple times.